# How can i get windows back

Tags: windows

I install Ubuntu on my laptop.the installation is successful but the problem is.already I install windows 7 at the time OS installation I choose another volume instead of win7 volume so my windows 7 is still present in my system is there any way to get back it

Comment: As long as it still exists, running `sudo update-grub` in the terminal should make it show up in the Ubuntu boot menu.

Comment: i use that command,but no change

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `sudo parted -l` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

If windows is present, you should be able to select at startup during the grub.

---

You don't precise which version you are working with so I add this comment :

I noticed with ubuntu 14.04 (maybe 15.04 too), grub may not appear.
If grub not appear edit file "/etc/default/grub" and comment "GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0".

You should now have something like this :

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Then update grub :

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Finally restart your computer and you should be able to select another system.

Comment: i use 14.04 . i use update command that shows win8 on bootselection.if i select that option nothing will happen

Comment: When you select windows 8 in grub, you stay on a black screen ?

Comment: Also chek this subject, it talks about dual boot with ubuntu and window 8 and seems very complete, check dualboot issues and troubleshooting  : http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: my os is windows 7 but i use win8 along inside cd.suppose that is cause this problem

Comment: yes #Inglebard it stay on black screen

Comment: sry for the late responce #lnglebrd.my problem is solved

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair  
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
boot-repair